# How to calculate block averages in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose, we have a DataFrame like so.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5), columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
idx = np.random.randint(0,2,(10,5))
df = abs(df * idx)
```

In my specific case

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.976492
1   0.000000    3.589563    0.000000    0.400287    0.000000
2   0.000000    0.000000    0.247323    0.000000    0.000000
3   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.079501    0.000000
4   0.136868    0.000000    0.223572    0.153744    0.000000
5   0.000000    0.000000    0.494390    0.311590    0.000000
6   0.000000    0.000000    0.756897    0.000000    0.039769
7   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1.006561    0.000000
8   0.651060    0.588797    0.000000    0.000000    0.028943
9   1.040841    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.879489
```

I would like to calculate the means of each non-zero blocks. For example, second to the last column (d column) would yield a series of the form:

```
0    0.000000
1    0.400287
2    0.000000
3    0.11662267564906763
4    0.11662267564906763
5    0.11662267564906763
6    0.000000
7    1.006561
8    0.000000
9    0.000000
```

**Clarification:**

What I meant by non-zero blocks is that for any given column, those blocks with consecutive non-zero entrys. For instance, column a would have 2 blocks, one occurs at index=4, value=0.136868, and the other occurs at index=8,9 and value = [0.651060,1040841]. I want the mean of each blocks.

**Clarification 2:**
In the case of column a, the output would be

```
0    0.000000
1    0.000000
2    0.000000
3    0.000000
4    0.136868
5    0.000000
6    0.000000
7    0.000000
8    0.8459504999999999
9    0.8459504999999999
```

where position 8,9 yields the average of the last two entries.

Comment: Can you explain more `means of each non-zero blocks` ? Why output is `0` if count not zero blocks?

Comment: @jezrael Please take a look at my update. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. But why output is not `(pd.Series([float1, float2,float3,float4,float5], index=['a','b','c','d','e']))` ? because need count means by columns ?

Comment: Because each column may have different number of blocks. So the output would just be of the same dimension as the original input DF, with each block entries being the mean of the block.

Comment: Ok, then output for first column is `0.136868 + (0.651060 + 1.040841)/2 = 0,9828185`. This number is where written? I think in last non zero row (in first column to row with index=9), but there is `0`. Sorry, still unclear for me.

Comment: Can you update question? Comment formating is terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get groups of consecutives values by [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to `df1`:

```
a = df != 0
df1 = (a != a.shift()).cumsum()
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  2  1  2  2
2  1  3  2  3  2
3  1  3  3  4  2
4  2  3  4  4  2
5  3  3  4  4  2
6  3  3  4  5  3
7  3  3  5  6  4
8  4  4  5  7  5
9  4  5  5  7  5
```

Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns from `df` per groups from `df1` with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
print (df.a.groupby([df1.a]).transform('mean'))
0    0.000000
1    0.000000
2    0.000000
3    0.000000
4    0.136868
5    0.000000
6    0.000000
7    0.000000
8    0.845951
9    0.845951
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

If need output of all columns use list comprehension with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df2 = pd.concat([df[col].groupby([df1[col]]).transform('mean') for col in df], axis=1)
print (df2)
          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.976492
1  0.000000  3.589563  0.000000  0.400287  0.000000
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.247323  0.000000  0.000000
3  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.181612  0.000000
4  0.136868  0.000000  0.491620  0.181612  0.000000
5  0.000000  0.000000  0.491620  0.181612  0.000000
6  0.000000  0.000000  0.491620  0.000000  0.039769
7  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  1.006561  0.000000
8  0.845951  0.588797  0.000000  0.000000  0.454216
9  0.845951  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.454216
```